# Custom binding to wrap selection in parentheses

Tags: vim

I have a nifty key combination to wrap a single word in parentheses: 
`cw(<C-r><C-o>")<ESC>`.

What I want to do is create a custom binding, `(`, which operates on any selection.

If I am in visual mode and have selected a block of text or several blocks, `(` should wrap all of the selected blocks in parentheses.

If I am in normal mode and type `(3j`, it should perform the combination `c3j(<C-r><C-o>")<ESC>`.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7):

What you need is `'opfunc'` and `g@` mappings for normal mode. So it would look like:

```
function WrapInParens(type, ...) abort
  let sel_save = &selection
  let &selection = "inclusive"
  let reg_save = @@

  if a:0  " Invoked from Visual mode, use gv command.
    silent exe "normal! gvc(\<C-r>\<C-o>\")"
  elseif a:type == 'line'
    silent exe "normal! '[V']c(\<C-r>\<C-o>\")"
  else
    silent exe "normal! `[v`]c(\<C-r>\<C-o>\")"
  endif

  let &selection = sel_save
  let @@ = reg_save
end

nnoremap ( :set opfunc=WrapInParens<CR>g@
```

Or similar.  This should give you overview (I haven't tested it)

---

However there are 2 plugins that offers such functionality without overriding `(`:

- [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) `ys<motion>)`
- [vim-sadwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich) `sa<motion>)`

Comment: I highly recommend standing the shoulders of giants here and using a plugin as suggested. I use surround and I find it terribly handy